# Vim Typescript Syntax Highlighting not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, vim, vim-plugin, macvim

I'm trying to set up syntax highlighting for typescript ts and tsx files. None of it works. Default vim highlighting is being applied instead. I tried both 'leafgarland/typescript-vim' and 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim' plugins and nothing works.
That's my .vimrc file:

```
set nocompatible              " required
filetype off                  " required

" set filetypes as typescript.tsx
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx,*.jsx set filetype=typescript.tsx
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts set filetype=typescript

" jump between matching html/xml/jxs tags
runtime macros/matchit.vim

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" adds color to commented out code
hi Comment ctermfg=LightBlue

" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plugin 'jnurmine/Zenburn'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'tomasiser/vim-code-dark'
Plugin 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plugin 'chemzqm/vim-jsx-improve' 
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

" Typescript support
Plugin 'Quramy/tsuquyomi'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plugin 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim'
Plugin 'peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript'

" comments out highlighted code with gcc
Plugin 'tpope/vim-commentary'
" add all your plugins here (note older versions of Vundle
" used Bundle instead of Plugin)

" ...

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required


set encoding=utf-8

" Enable folding
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99

" Enable folding with the spacebar
nnoremap <space> za

let python_highlight_all=1

colorscheme codedark

set nu
set clipboard=unnamed

" Open NERD Tree when no file specified.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif

" Open NERD Tree when directory is specified.
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | ene | endif

" map Ctrl+n to toggling the NERD Tree
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

" Close NERD Tree when everything else is closed.
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif

" Keep NERD Tree open in new tabs
autocmd BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMirror

" Sets java script and html indentation to 2 spaces.
autocmd FileType html setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2
autocmd FileType json setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2

let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter = "\u00a0"

" Preven Ctrlp from searching node modules and git
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|DS_Store\|git'

filetype plugin on
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete


syntax on
```

Is it some missing option or some conflict? Jsx and js syntax highlighting works perfectly.

Comment: You've commented out the required plugin: `" Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'`. Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: I doesn't work when it is on either. I tried every option, switching on and off all the plugins in case something is in conflict. I think something doesn't connect typescript type file to the leafgarland/typescript-vim plugin but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: I'll update the code sample so that it doesn't confuse people.

Comment: Comment out every other Plugin and check. If typescript highlighting works uncomment plugins in groups.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't help. Also, file is being recognised as typescript or typescript.jsx. If I type ''':syntax''' it will show typescript syntax file and ''':set syntax''' shows '''syntax=typescript.tsx'''. It just doesn't color the text in any other way than default vim colours. It's same for both yats.vim and vim-jsx-typescript. Any other custom file type i.e. jsx, python etc. has proper highlighting. Typescript is the only problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Swapping these two:

```
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
Plugin 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim'
```

Like so:

```
Plugin 'HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim'
Plugin 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
```

seems to do it for me.